# Triac SRR causes conducted emission noise with active heater connected to 120V AC

Tags: ac, noise, solid-state-relay, triac, heater

I have a device that controls a silicone rubber heater, which is an active load and whose resistance does not change a lot when heating.
250W heater for 110V has about 50 Ohm cold resistance, which is about 2A which is about what it is at 120V at full power.

I control it with a G3NE-205T-US DC5 SSR, which is a 240V AC capable 5A AC triac switch with opto input.
The SSR is control from a digital circuit that puts 5V across the input, a MOSFET Low Side switch (pull to GND).
The SSR is zero-crossing, and is beings switched for at least 10 seconds ON and then 30 seconds OFF. So, no switching noise due to firing angle control, no such nonsense.

I have conducted emissions when the relay is ON. When it is off I am way down under the CLASS B FCC. When it is on, I am way over, about 5dB or so. Or 5dB under CLASS A.

So why I think it is the SSR? The last test I did was, while the SSR was energized and the board was thinking it was controlling it by applying the ON voltage, I shorted the relay's output. And the noise immediately went away, with the load being connected to power and the input being controlled as usual.

I do not get it what could be causing this. Yes I could put am RC snubber and all other stuff, but I would like to understand, where the noise is from?
(Oh......the noise is ... 150kHz. Which is nothing I have in mhy controls, and the DCDC power supply that makes 5V is 100kHz.)

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: You have the 1uF capacitor on the mains input?

Comment: Kartman, No, it is 0.2uF as a part of Schaffner filtering. It also has a CM choke of 2mH. I know they say in the datasheet 1uF "to comply with EMC directive ".

I am trying to understand what could be causing the noise before I simply suppress it with extra filtering. 
It's just like this: the Triac conducts - there is noise; the triac conducts but is shorted out by a wire - no noise.
I have just been told, I could take Class A (I pass with  5-6dB margin) and be done, but I am trying find out what it is that produces the noise. If it is the triac, I fail to understand how it could do this.

Comment: It could be some ringing when the triac commutates off. You should be able to see this on the oscilloscope.

Comment: There is no ringing. There is a step, yes, but no ringing whatsoever. Of course the step is in itself a harmonic-carrying thing.
I found an article that talks about it and recommends Crydom-Sensata LN series, which supposedly brings the noise under FCC Part B level.

Comment: Well. This particular SSR (Omron) obviously has a higher current jump when turning on.
I found a Crydom SSR that does it at half the amplitude and about 10 times slower, so I hope this will curb the emissions.

Comment: Hi, @morzh! may I know how your project went and if you sorted this out? I'm working on similar thing..

Comment: Greengold, 

Thanks for asking. The project turned out fine; we have been shipping this product for over a year. On one hand, I found a relay that, if used, would allow for Class B conducted to pass. On the other hand, I simply changed the input module for the 6A one (I used 10A initially) which has a bit larger value CM choke in the filter (methinks 0.3mH vs 0.2mH), which brought us to pass CLASS A, which is what we needed anyway.